# Why is it "wrinkled his nose in disgust AT the smell" instead of "in disgust OF the smell"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I came across this sentence:

> He wrinkled his nose in disgust **at** the smell.

I wonder why not:

> He wrinkled his nose in disgust **of** the smell.

Does it make any difference why we don't use *of*?

Comment: Have you ever seen *of* used this way? Why do you think that is?

Comment: @FeliniusRex I don't seem to have seen it,but I'm learning English(not my native language) ,so I ask why this is so here.Maybe there is a rule or you need to remember it.according to my logic, the value here is "because of this" and I would put *of*

Comment: In this particular sentence, *at* means **because of** and *of* simply doesn't mean that...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko okey,thanks

Comment: Ok. *At* here is common for body parts; you *wrinkle your nose at*, you *stare at*, you *raise your eyebrows at*, you *smile at* and so on. The idea is that you are responding to something outside yourself -- in this case, he is responding to a smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure there is an answer to *why* we use **at** instead of **of** that is substantially better than "Because that is the way English is."  I am sure your native language also has cases where you use one preposition and not another.

But we often use **at** to mean "caused by" in the case of reactions, or to mean "on the occasion of".

> [Stephen smiled at the thought](https://books.google.com/books?id=n384AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22smiled%20at%20the%20thought%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj78dfcxYjvAhXCmOAKHUB_DRcQ6AEwBXoECAIQAg)

> [He frowned at the interruption](https://books.google.com/books?id=-No-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA267&dq=%22frowned%20at%20the%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbyJ7txYjvAhWIdN8KHXKuCzUQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg)

> [Richard's nose wrinkled at the stink](https://books.google.com/books?id=sNkKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22wrinkled%20at%20the%22&dq=%22wrinkled%20at%20the%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPl-eQxojvAhVydt8KHcY4CR0Q6AEwBXoECAMQAg)

Comment: This is the whole of the answer. _Disgust_ happens to take "at" or "with", but not "of". There is no rule or explanation: it is is part of the dictionary entry of the word.